# Flutter convert setState to Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am trying to understand how to do a bloc pattern in Flutter.

From the bloc docs:

1. A bloc is a class.
2. An event is a response to user interactions.
3. An event handler is responsible for converting any incoming events into zero or more outgoing states.
4. The change from one state to another is called a Transition.
5. A transition occurs when a new event is added and a new state is emitted from a corresponding EventHandler.
6. Transition consists of the current state, the event, and the next state.
7. BlocProvider is a widget that provides a BLoC to its child widgets.
8. Blocs should never directly emit new states. Instead every state change must be output in response to an incoming event within an EventHandler.
9. The builder function returns a widget in response to the state.

I read the official docs on Bloc and even tried to understand the simple example, but I am not quite grasping what are the key parts of the Flutter bloc pattern.

I understood that anytime I have setState, then that's the part I need to change to Bloc and I should not touch the general layout.

I came up with a more realistic example(compared to examples given in the official bloc docs) using setState approach.

I need someone to verbally explain key parts of a bloc approach based on this example.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  static const String title = 'Flutter Sample';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: title,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(title)),
            body: const MyStatefulWidget()));
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool light = true;
  List<String> names = [];
  TextEditingController nc = TextEditingController();
  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      names.add(nc.text);
      getList();
    });
  }

  List<Widget> getList() {
    listWidget = [];
    listWidget = names.map((p) => Text(p)).toList();
    return listWidget;
  }

  void deleteItemFromList() {
    setState(() {
      if (names.isEmpty) return;
      names.removeLast();
    });
  }

  clearInput() {
    setState(() {
      nc.text = "";
    });
  }

  bool x = true;

  enableInput() {
    setState(() {
      x != x;
    });
  }

  List<Widget> listWidget = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget test1 = const Text("Hello Flutter");
    Widget test2 = Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: TextField(
            enabled: x,
            controller: nc,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Name')));
    Widget test3 = SwitchListTile(
        value: x,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            x = value;
          });
        });
    Widget buttons = SizedBox(
      width: 1000,
      height: 30,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: clearInput, child: const Text('ClearInput'))),
          Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: addItemToList, child: const Text('Add'))),
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: deleteItemFromList,
              child: const Text('Remove'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget mylist = ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return listWidget[index];
        });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[test1, test2, test3, buttons, mylist],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Changing a `setState` approach to a BLoC approach isn't simply replacing all of your `setState` calls to `bloc` equivalents. It's an architectural change, which means you will likely have to refactor the widgets themselves to work with the new design in mind. Showing you how to do this is beyond the scope of StackOverflow, though. There are numerous Youtube tutorials on how the BLoC pattern works, so I recommend starting there.

Comment: give a try, then we will be happy to fix the error